# Proof of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x}$ procedure

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

Proof of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x}$  (Is it correct?):

We assume that the limit is equal to 1, $L = 1$. We need to show that there exists $|x- 1|<\delta$ such that $|\sqrt{x}-1| < \epsilon$ for all epsilon bigger than zero.

Let's find $\delta$:
$$|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon\\
|\sqrt{|x|}-1| = \sqrt{|x-1+1|}-1 \leq \sqrt{|x-1|+1}-1\leq\sqrt{\delta+1}-1<\epsilon$$

Now we solve the equation for delta:
$$\sqrt{\delta+1}-1<\epsilon \iff \sqrt{\delta+1}<\epsilon + 1 \iff \delta+1<(\epsilon + 1)^2\iff \delta< (\epsilon + 1)^2 -1 $$

$$\delta := \{(\epsilon + 1)^2 -1 \}$$

Now the proof:
$$|x-1| < (\epsilon + 1)^2 -1 \\
\sqrt{|x-1|+1} < (\epsilon + 1) \quad\text{we know that the left and the right side are always positive before square rooting.}\\
\sqrt{|x-1+1|}+1 < \epsilon \iff |\sqrt{|x|}+1| < \epsilon $$
$x$ is always bigger than or equal to zero, so:$$|\sqrt{x}+1| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in line $ 7 $ when you wrote

$$|\sqrt{|x|}-1|=\sqrt{|x-1+1|}-1$$

if $ 0\le x<1 $, it is not true.

Comment: I see, is there any way I could get around this error ?

Comment: Just before i answer your question, i had 57123 and just after you upvoted ( thanks) it became 57098. ??

Comment: I do not know why that would happen

Answer (score 1):

**Check:**

As the square root is a monotonous function, it suffices to verify the inequalities at the endpoints of the intervals:

$$1+\delta=(1+\epsilon)^2\to 1+\epsilon-1=\epsilon$$

but

$$1-\delta=2-(1+\epsilon)^2\to \sqrt{1-2\epsilon-\epsilon^2}-1\color{red}<-\epsilon.$$

[image]

---

**Correct solution:**

$$1-\epsilon<\sqrt{1-\delta}<\sqrt{1+\delta}<1+\epsilon$$
$$-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2<-\delta<\delta<2\epsilon+\epsilon^2$$

and

$$\delta<2\epsilon-\epsilon^2.$$

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction if I am not mistaking right?

Comment: @BiliDebili: no, just verification of the inequations.

Comment: From where can we say that $1-\epsilon < \sqrt{1-\delta}$

Comment: @BiliDebili $|\sqrt x-1|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Is it like this: $\sqrt{x} <\epsilon + 1 \iff \sqrt{1-1+x} < \epsilon+1 \iff \sqrt{1+\delta} < \epsilon+1$ . I tried to derive it but I get + $\delta$ instead of minus. How did you derive it?

Comment: @BiliDebili: what is the range of $x$ ?

Comment: From zero to infinity

Comment: @BiliDebili: mh, you have a second chance...

Comment: Oh I see it is $(1- \delta, 1 +\delta)$